# Can't put custom class in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, session

I have an asp.net website and at one point I use some jquery ajax calls. So far I've been able to put a entity object into session, but this morning I found that as soon as I try and put a custom class in session it goes wrong somehow. I say somehow as I am not able to catch any errors, but the ajax call fails.

If I take out the line in the C# code, it runs fine. Even a class with no properties in it will not work.

To access the session from the static WebMethod I use: HttpContext.Current.Session

I must be missing something.
Nick

Comment: What was the error logged in console for you ajax request?

Comment: The code is A LOT, but what needs to happen is simple. 
HttpContext.Current.Session = InstanceOfMyClass;

That's it. It really is as simple as that and if I change InstanceOfMyClass to anything else like DateTime it works. In firebug all I get is a Internal Server Error and then syntax error which seems to come from JQuery. Not sure why JQuery gets this syntax error, but this is what firebug prints out in green: (<!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class that is serializable can be stored in Sessions. Entity objects are serializable.
Mark your custom class with the `[Serializable]` attribute and try again.